# Updating a static final field from an instance initializer

Tags: java

Java prohibits access of a final static field from an initializer. For example:

```
public enum Example {
    ValueA("valueAA", "valueAB"),
    ValueB("valueBA", "valueBB");

    final static Map<String, Example> exampleByPropertyA = new HashMap<>();

    final String propertyA;
    final String propertyB;

    Example(String propertyA, String propertyB) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
        this.propertyB = propertyB;

        Example.exampleByPropertyA.put(propertyA, this); // <- Not permitted
    }
}
```

However, if the update to the static `Map` is performed in a separate method that is called by the initializer, this is fine. For example:

```
public enum Example {
    ValueA("valueAA", "valueAB"),
    ValueB("valueBA", "valueBB");

    final static Map<String, Example> exampleByPropertyA = new HashMap<>();

    final String propertyA;
    final String propertyB;

    Example(String propertyA, String propertyB) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
        this.propertyB = propertyB;

        addExample(this);
    }

    private addExample(Example example) {
        Example.exampleByPropertyA.put(example.propertyA, example); // <- Permitted
    }
}
```

Given this context, my question is: Does a call to a member method constitute a "freeze action" or is it indicative to the JVM that the object is, for all intents and purposes, "initialized"? Curious why this makes a difference.

I've done some searching, but haven't found anything that articulates this well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze action"? Do you mean a "blocking" method call?

Comment: No, I was talking about a final field freeze action.

Comment: @sellc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1

Comment: Interesting, I have never run across that before. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a call to a member method constitute a "freeze action" or is it indicative to the JVM that the object is, for all intents and purposes, "initialized"? Curious why this makes a difference.

The problem is that your class is initialised top to bottom. This means your static fields have not been initialised yet i.e. your Map is `null`.

Another approach is to add a static initialisation block to be called after everything has been initialised.

```
static {
    for (Example e: values()) {
        addExample(e);
    }
}

private static addExample(Example example) {
    Example prev = exampleByPropertyA.put(example.propertyA, example);
    assert prev == null;
}
```

---

NOTE: You can see a final variable before it is initialised.  This means `final` can have a before and after value even without using reflection.

```
public class A {
    final String text = getText();

    private String getText() {
        System.out.println("text= " + text);
        return "is set";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new A().getText();
    }
}
```

prints

```
text= null
text= is set
```

Using reflection you can alter `final` fields even after initialisation though you should avoid doing this unless there is no other option.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Gosh. I knew that, but I hadn't considered that in the context of an enumeration. I can't accept your answer for another 8 minutes or so, but that makes total sense. I knew I had to be overlooking something like that. Thank you!

Comment: "final" variables cannot have value changed or be updated,

Comment: @SAMUELMARCHANT - Yes, I understand that, but if you take a deep-dive into the Java Memory Model, you'll find that certain things invoke the "freezing" of those final values. Final values that are initialized after such a freeze action are not necessarily "final".

Comment: @SAMUELMARCHANT static final can be accessed before they are initialised.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do what you're trying to do, is to write a static initializer, which runs *after* all the enums have been created.

*Defensive programming:* You should also add a simple check to guard against programming errors.

```
public enum Example {
    ValueA("valueAA", "valueAB"),
    ValueB("valueBA", "valueBB");

    final static Map<String, Example> exampleByPropertyA = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Example ex : values())
            if (exampleByPropertyA.put(ex.propertyA, ex) != null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate propertyA: " + ex.propertyA);
    }

    final String propertyA;
    final String propertyB;

    Example(String propertyA, String propertyB) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for making the case from a "Defensive Coding" perspective. Both answers make total sense, but I'm going to accept Peter's answer since he got to it first. Thank. you for the timely response, though!

Comment: @AndySenn But my code is complete, while Peter's code is missing `addExample` and can't use yours since yours is not static. --- Naw, it's fine. You accept whichever answer you like best. ;-)

Comment: Point taken, but that method was defined in my example, so it made sense. No hard feelings! :)

Comment: Not sure this is worthy of a catchable `IllegalStateException` I would use an AssertionError.